# jquery get a href using attr() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page* with several `.article` divs with the following markup:

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="featured-img">
    <a href="https://www.johornow.com/english/things-to-do-at-kota-tinggi/" style="background: none;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="featured-info">
    <h3 class="article-title">
      <a href="https://www.johornow.com/english/things-to-do-at-kota-tinggi/">Fun Things to Do and Amazing Places to Visit at Kota Tinggi</a>
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to get all the anchor links:

```
$('.article').each( e => $(this).find('article-title').find('a').attr("href") )
```

Surprisingly I failed to do so, I got DOM node. What's wrong with my code?!

*https://www.johornow.com/english/travel/

Comment: It is not a DOM node, `$.each()` returns a jQuery object

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes so how can I get links?

Comment: Perhaps: `find('.article-title')`  (I didn't look at the dodgy-looking link, so if you want more info, please include some relevant html - but it's likely it's `<div class='article-title'>` so you need the `.` in the selector.)

Comment: `[].map.apply($('a'), [x=>x.href])`

Comment: Can we please see the related HTML ?

Comment: @freedomn-m oh ya i missed that, but still doesn't work

Comment: @devlincarnate the URL is here.

Comment: Use `function() {}` with jQuery, or `this` is undefined. You also forgot that dot for `.article-title`.

Comment: @JennyMok - you should edit your question and add the relevant HTML to the body of your question (i.e.  not a link to the site).  This is because 1) your question loses meaning to future readers if the link goes bad and 2) some people have strict internet filters that may prevent them from visiting the link 3) we shouldn't have to weed through a bunch of HTML to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of errors in your code:

1) JQuery is all about chaining, that's why functions like `each` return the initial set and not the elements you return in the function (or a collection of your return values?). What you want/need here is `.map`.

2) your find was missing the `.` for addressing a class. Also, you can write it in a single statement `find(".article-title a")`.

3) Fat arrow functions don't establish their own context, thus `$(this)` won't work. Instead you have to use the "old-school" way of writing functions, to actually have `this` refer to the single elements.

The following jquery solution

```
$('.article .article-title a').map( function(){return console.log($(this).attr("href"))} )
```

creates an array with all the link hrefs.

So does the following vanilla JS (which I actually always prefer):

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.article .article-title a'), e=>e.href )
```

There you have your fancy fat arrow again - also, it's shorter, (possibly faster) and does not rely on third-party;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the links in an array

```
var m =[];
$('.article').each(function(e,v){
m.push($(this).find('h3 > a').attr("href"))
})
console.log(m)
```

Comment: How about a simple `.map` which would result in pretty much exactly the code I wrote in my answer? ;-)